# How to add_post_meta() wordpress with JavaScript or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to modify a plugin.

Right now I would like to modify the price it outputs.

I have set up radio inputs, and would like to add the selected value to post_meta.

```
<?php 
    $eventTitle = get_the_title($event->data->ID);

    if($eventTitle == 'Shabba') { 
    echo '<span> I will join the meal/s on: </span><br>
        <input type="radio" name="shabba" value="1" onchange="shabReserv()">Friday Night<br>
        <input type="radio" name="shabba" value="2" onchange="shabReserv()">Shabbat Day<br>
        <input type="radio" name="shabba" value="3" checked onchange="shabReserv()">Both<br><br>
        '; 
    }    

    else{
    }
    ?>
```

For now I have tried using XMLHttpRequest() and fetch() to try to post the value and then recover it with $_POST or $_REQUEST, but neither of these options work. I have also tried adding  add_post_meta() within my javascript, but I cannot seem to pass the javascript variable correctly, sometimes I am left with a plain string.

```
<script>


    var he = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='shabba']")
                var formData = new FormData()
                   var shabForm = document.getElementById('mec_book_form<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>')
                   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function shabReserv(){
        for(i=0; he.length > i;i++){
            if(he[i].checked){
                console.log(he[i].value)
                return he[i].value
//attempt                
                    request.open("POST", '/', true);
                    request.send(shabForm)


// attempt
                    formData.set('shabba', he[i].value);
                        fetch('/', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: formData
                        })
                <?php $shabb = "<script>return formData.get('shabba')</script>";
                 add_post_meta($event_id,'shabba2', $shabb); ?>

            }

        }
    }
    shabReserv()

</script>
```

the goal is to be able to retrieve the value of the radio input through get_post_meta - on the same page (mult-step form)

$event_tickets = get_post_meta($event_id, 'mec_tickets', true);

such that $event_tickets[$ticket_id]['shabba']  witll give me the value of the field previosly mentioned

Please help me add_post_meta with javascript